# Changing an element in position absolute

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project and I have an element that is set in "position : absolute", but it's only text and an animation. I know it's better not to use that kind of position in that case.
How can i change it to look the same but without the position absolute ? Can I use a display flex with space between ? If I use space between, do I need to add another div in HTML ?

```css
.meal div {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #0000002e;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    height: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    animation: fadeIn 0.7s ease-in both, top 0.5s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.meal__price {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 85%; 
}
.price {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2rem;
    top: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.meal h3, .meal__description {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.meal h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 70%;
}
.meal__description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 90%;
}
.meal span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #99E2D0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    bottom: 0rem;
    width: 0%;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.9rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.9rem;
    left: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.375rem;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.fa-check-circle {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.meal div:hover span {
    left: 80%;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 20%;
}
.meal div:hover .meal__price {
    left: 65%;
}
.meal div:hover .meal__description {
    width: 50%;
}
.meal div:hover i {
    animation: rotation 0.4s linear 0.15s forwards;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        visibility: visible;
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.meal div:hover .meal__price {
        animation: move-animation 0.2s linear forwards;
    }

@keyframes move-animation {
    from {
        left: 85%;
    }
    to {
        left: 70%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="meal">
<div>
   <h3>Pigeonneau d’Ille-et-Vilaine</h3>
   <p class="meal__description">Sur son lit de gnocchis aux légumes</p>
   <p class="meal__price">44€</p>
  <span>
     <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I see a lot of elements with `position:absolute`. What is _the_ element you're talking about?

Comment: Mostly : meal__price, .price, meal h3, and meal__description, the span is fine in absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `position: absolute` on elements that only consist of text or images is absolutely fine depending on the context.
But I would agree, in this case you could have achieved the same layout without resorting to `position: absolute`, which takes elements out of the flow.

Also, not using `position: absolute` means that we won't have to rely on magic numbers! Currently you are setting `.meal div` to a fixed height, regardless of its content. This feels wrong, but won't be necessary if its children are still part of its flow.

And trying to use CSS Flex here is a great idea! In fact, I will use Flex in combination with Grid for re-styling your meal card.

(**Sidenote:** There are obviously very many ways to achieve what you asked for, as you have obviously noticed. This is just the way *I* did it, and I highly encourage you to explore alternatives for this—and for other things, too!—yourself before reading this. Once you know a way, you're less likely to develop a unique solution yourself.)

Here are the things in your CSS I would like to change:

1. Regarding your `<span>`:
   Currently, it overflows `.meal` on small width values. This lets your card look poorly or amateurishly done.
2. Remove dead code: Some declarations (or even whole rule sets, e.g. `.price`'s) are unused, we can remove them.
3. `position: absolute`: This is what your question is actually about.

Fixing 2. is a simple matter of deleting. I don't think that requires any further explanation.

To fix 1. we can add `overflow: hidden` to the rule for `.meal div`. With this, we won't need the border on the right sides of `span`, since those will be hidden by the property we just set.
Here is an extreme example showing the differences:

```css
/* Don't set border-radius when using overflow:hidden! */
.outer:not(.overflow)>.inner {border-radius: 9999px;}
.overflow {overflow: hidden}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background-color: crimson;
  transition: height .5s;
}
.outer {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  width: 10rem;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.outer:hover>.inner {height: 100%}

/* Ignore; CSS to make the example look nicer */
body {display:flex;gap:1rem}
header {text-align:center}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>With <code>overflow: hidden</code></header>
  <div class="outer overflow">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <header>Previously</header>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

## Re-style for Flex (and Grid!)

We don't want to use `position: absolute` anymore, so we remove those declarations as well as any related. This means, we also remove:

- `position: relative`: We don't need a non-static predecessor.
- `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`: We cannot use these anymore.

### Distributing the space

What I take from the looks of it is, that we basically want 3 columns:

1. Title and description.
2. Price.
3. The turquoise `<span>` that expands on hover (and as per the code, has a FontAwesome icon on top of it?).

Currently, these are all siblings. But styling will be easier if we wrap all except the `<span>`. In doing so, we can style the title, description and price tag without affecting the left out `<span>`.
An example of how we can wrap them:

```html
<div class="meal">
  <div>
    <div>
      <h3></h3>
      <p class="meal__description"></p>
      <p class="meal__price"></p>
    </div>
    <span>
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But one of your selectors is `.meal div`, which will select the inner `<div>` as well. We can simply fix this by using a [*child combinator* (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) instead of a [*descendant combinator* ( , space)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator): `.meal>div`.

### The CSS

The first instance where Flex seems fit, is for placing the new wrapper `<div>` and the `<span>` side-by-side. Also, we want the wrapper to take up the remaining space:

```css
.meal>div {display:flex}
.meal>div>div {flex-grow:1}
/* Take up remaining space. The (non-zero) value is relevant
   if other flex children have this property declared as well.
   Then, the flex parent will distribute the remaining space
   according to the *weight* (e.g. this value) of the children. */
```

The content of the wrapper however should be organized in 2 columns: 1 for the title and description, and 1 for the price. We can either wrap title and description in yet another wrapper, or we can use Grid to make our lives easier:

```css
.meal>div>div {
  display:grid;
  /* 1fr is very similar to 'flex-grow: 1', just for Grid instead of Flex. */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto); /* Alternatively: auto auto */
}
.meal__price {
  grid-column: 2/2;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  /* "Take up all rows between
     the first and the last, inclusively" */
}
```

After some small changes to make it look more similar to the original version, this is what we end up with:

```css
.fa-check-circle {visibility: hidden}
.meal>div {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  animation: fadeIn 0.7s ease-in both, top 0.5s linear;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #0000002e;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.meal>div>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
}
.meal>div>div * {margin:0}
.meal>div:hover i {animation: rotation 0.4s linear 0.15s forwards}
.meal>div:hover span {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 6rem;
}
.meal h3, .meal__description {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.meal__price {
  place-self: flex-end;
  grid-column: 2/2;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.meal span {
  width: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background-color: #99E2D0;
  font-size: 1.375rem;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="meal">
  <div>
    <div>
      <h3>Pigeonneau d’Ille-et-Vilaine</h3>
      <p class="meal__description">Sur son lit de gnocchis aux légumes</p>
      <p class="meal__price">44€</p>
    </div>
    <span>
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just to practice some CSS again, I tried recreating your code as closely as possible, purely from what I can see. Since I think reading others' CSS is helpful, I provided it here as well:

```css
.meal {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: .2rem .15rem .6rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.meal::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  background-color: #99E2D0;
  transition: width .6s;
}
.meal:hover::after {width: 6rem}
.meal>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-block: .8rem;
  padding-inline: 1rem;
  display:
}
.meal header {
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.meal .price {
  clear: right;
  float: right;
}
p:last-child {margin-block-end:0}
```

```html
<section class="meal">
  <div>
    <header>Pigeonneau d’Ille-et-Vilaine</header>
    <p class="description">
      Sur son lit de gnocchis aux légumes
      <span class="price">Price: 44€</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What a great answer!